# Nullable ->enabled, getter of [JsonIgnore] propety called when post

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, serialization, nullable

Hello I am trying the simple asp.net 6 code bellow.

When I set the project **nullable setting to disable**, and call person controller post method, the getter of `Person.Surname` **isn't** calling. That's OK. It's calling only the `Person.Name` getter.

When I set in project **nullable setting to enable**,and call person controller post method, the getter of `Person.Surname` **is** calling. And the getter of `Person.Name` is called two times.

Here is the reason from the stack trace:
\TestNet6.WebApplication\Person.cs:line 30
at **Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyHelper.CallNullSafePropertyGetter**[TDeclaringType,TValue](Func`2 getter, Object target)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.DefaultComplexObjectValidationStrategy.Enumerator.<>c__DisplayClass13_1.b__1()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationEntry.get_Model()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitChildren(IValidationStrategy strategy)
....

When i set nullable to disable then is no getter, CallNullSafePropertyGetter, and model validation called.

**That means,the project nullable enable/disable setting change application behavior at runtime.**

repository:
https://github.com/PetoLuc/TestNet6

controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class PersonController : ControllerBase
{       
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(Person person)
    {

    }   
}
```

model:

```
public class Person
{           
    private string? name;       
    private string? surname;

    public string? Name 
    {
        get
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("get name is calling");
            return name;
        }
        set 
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("set name is calling");
            name = value;
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]        
    public string? Surname 
    {
        get
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("get surname is calling");
            return surname;
        }
        set
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("set surname is calling");
            surname = value;
        }
    }
}
```

client:

```
await new HttpClient().PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:5032/person/post", new Dol.Person { Name = "test" });
```

Comment: Try trace-writing the stack trace from those locations, maybe that will shed some light on why it happens.

Comment: I can't repro this at all. Are you sure it's not just the debugger reading the values? That can happen even if you hover your mouse over the object when it's running.

Comment: Which serialization library are you using? Newtonsoft or System.Text.Json or XYZ? (From the `JsonIgnoreAttribute` I could not tell)

Comment: I updated the question, and added the applicaiton repo. When nullable is enabled then is CallNullSafePropertyGetter called. That's reason why was the getter called.